# stack rebuild all all packages

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

## Question

Is there a way to force `stack` to rebuild all local precompiled packages?

## Context

I had a working `stack` installation but I've updated my ArchLinux (including kernel update) and I get this now:

```
stack ghci
Main.hs: <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../lib/libncurses.so (-lncursesw: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

Since the given exists my guess is that the compiled version isn't linked correctly, that's why I try to rebuild everything.

Comment: It should be sufficient to wipe out the .stack directory in your home directory.

Comment: I would back up my ~/.stack/config.yaml and ~/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml as well :)

Comment: This may also be an issue with your libncurses installation. Reinstalling it / installing a different version may be helpful.